# Is it possible to move a question from stackoverflow to sharepoint.stackexchange?

Tags: support, migrated-questions

I have a question which was asked on stackoverflow but it would be best if it was on sharepoint.stackexchange. I was looking at flagging it but the only migrate options do not include sharepoint.stackexchange. Is there any way?

The question is:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741684/sharepoint-template-bug-workflow-fix-not-working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flag it for moderator attention and choose the `other` option. Then in the comments box explain where it should be migrated and why.

Comment: Ah...I was selecting "It doesn't belong here." That makes sense though. Cheers.